# How to upload a Excel Sheet data into Mysql table using codeigniter library?

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I am looking for CI library to upload a Excel Sheet Data into MySql Table. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this before.

The way I accomplised this task was by including PHPExcel (https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) as a third party library in CodeIgniter.

Then I wrote a controller that read the file using PHPExcel, put in it into an array and then inserted that array into my db using CI's built in database library.